# Agora Cloud Recording API query (get request) responding 404

Tags: api, amazon-s3, postman, agora.io

I am using Agora Cloud Recording Postman Collection and getting 200 for acquire and start (POST request) and entered the channel.

When I call query (GET request), I get "code": 404 in the response.
I am using AWS S3 for my cloud storage and I can save other files with AccessKey and Secret so I am thinking the storageConfig has no problem...

Is there anything I am missing in the request body of start...? or is there any possible reason why I am getting 404 for my query? My request body is

```
{
    "cname": "{{AccessChannel}}",
    "uid": "{{RecordingUID}}",
    "clientRequest": {
        "recordingConfig": {
            "channelType": 0,
            "streamTypes": 2,
            "audioProfile": 1,
            "videoStreamType": 0,
            "maxIdleTime": 120,
            "transcodingConfig": {
                "width": 360,
                "height": 640,
                "fps": 30,
                "bitrate": 600,
                "maxResolutionUid": "1",
                "mixedVideoLayout": 1
            }
        },
        "storageConfig": {
            "vendor": {{StorageVendor}},
            "region": {{StorageRegion}},
            "bucket": "{{Bucket}}",
            "accessKey": "{{AccessKey}}",
            "secretKey": "{{SecretKey}}"
        }
    }
}
```

My environment setting. Acquire and Start responses are 200 but I get 404 in the responses of Query and Stop.

[environment setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeViR.png)

[acquire response is 200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gqlL.png)

[start response is 200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0QsK.png)

[I get code: 404 in the response of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILur6.png)

[Also for stop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApuZA.png)

Comment: Just make sure that you are using the valid configuration, as invalid configuration may lead to 'start' method response to 200 OK, but recording is not started due to invalid configuration. In that case if you 'query' status you will get 404 not found, because there is no recording going on associated with that sid and resource-id.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/cloud_recording_api_rest?platform=RESTful

start uses POST not GET thats why you are getting 404 , there is no endpoint that supports GET

Comment: I use POST request for start. I am getting 404 when I call query which requires method: GET https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/cloud_recording_api_rest?platform=RESTful#query

Comment: Add postman screenshot please so that we can now what exactly you are doing

Comment: Did you first do a post to start recording ? That endpoint you mentioned works only if recording is in progress

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added pics for each call. I first do a post to acquire and after that I call start. I make sure to enter the channel to be broadcasting but the recording is not working even though the response of start is 200.

Comment: are you doing in the sequence aquire,start , do GET order?

Comment: Yes I first get acquire and call start then query. Since the query responds with code: 404 I  get code: 404 in the stop as well... I was wondering my clientRequest in the body of start has something not correct so I checked with their documentation but I couldn't find the specific reason...

Answer (score 0):

Here are some possible reasons you could be getting the 404: https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/faq/return-404.

From looking at your transcoding config, it looks like your transcoding config isn't set properly. You will need to switch the width and height of the config. Make sure that all your transcoding parameters comply with the following table: https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/recording_video_profile?platform=RESTful

Also, you shouldn't give `maxResolutionUid` when your `mixedVideoLayout` is `1`.

Another reason you could be getting this error is if you have enabled app certificate in your agora project. If you have, then you are required to specify the token in the body of this request. You can see the relevant API Reference here: https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/cloud_recording_api_rest?platform=RESTful#a-namestartastart-cloud-recording

Comment: Thank you so so much for your kind explanation. The token was the thing I needed to include in the body of start. After I could solve the code: 404 issue, I receive "code": 435 in the response of stop although I am in the channel and I can see my web streaming from my mobile. Is this mean I am giving the wrong cname...? I am giving the channel name which I stream via web as a host.

Comment: Are you making sure the App ID and the channel name are the same for when you are using the web client as well as cloud recording?